# Missing DB entries

Tags: mysql, php

I have run into a problematic situation.

I oversee the administration of 5 php web pages on one server, each having their own database. All pages work like interactive forms drawing and storing data into the DB. They all have the same structure but with different variables and screen outputs.

A few days ago between 22:00 and 06:00 (exactly the night when the leap second was applied), one of the web pages did not store any entries into its DB. All the other worked fine. From the error and access logs in apache it looks like that during that night, there was no traffic from the webpage at all, so it looks like a connection problem. The users report that everything was working fine which we later confirmed with camera footage and also several temp files on their computer. These are rests of generated data that was sent into their printer.

I tried to check the cable and it is ok. Page also informs the user if there is a problem with the DB. And I do not think that they could work from cached site data for all night long since there would be problems with the DB connection. The data was not deleted because the auto-increment ID's are ok. I also thought of the leap second but all pages use the same date time function and there were no other problems reported after it was applied. Also data was missing even before the leap second was applied. After 06:00 the storage of new data functioned as normal while there was no one that did anything either with the site or the database.

Me and my boss have run out of ideas what could be wrong. Anybody experienced something similar? 
And some server info:

```
Debian 6.0.6
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
MySQL client version: 5.1.66
```

If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Thank you

Comment: Single machine (no Master-Slave)?  Anything in `mysqd.err`?

Comment: single machine and nothing in the log. Other mysql logs were disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Weird behaviour.

**sql**

Just because the auto increments are "ok" it does not mean the data has not been deleted. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number it can be changed via alter table.

**traffic**

That there were no traffic by the webpage is weird as users worked with the website. Is it possible that the server could not be accessed and another server were uses during the time?

**got hacked?**

I would check wether someone connected via ssh or so and did some bad stuff via shell. Also check your system for malware.

**other local scripts/programmes**

*I don't think this the reason but for completeness I added that.*

Do you have any script or programme running that does sth. with sql and could have caused this (e.g. bug)?

Comment: Hi. i think we do not use any alter table queries. but i will check in the morning.


4 out of 5 sites worked normally and all these sites are accessed from 1-2 locations which worked flawlessy for about 3 months since the last code update


also the server is only accessible only from the internal network so if we got hacked this would be the smallest problem. But i will check for malware.


and i do not think there is any script or programme that accesses the DB besides the webpages.

Comment: We also encountered the same behaviour on another site this morning. Some elements of the page were also shifted from their original position. Users are using chrome to get to the website and after restarting chrome everything worked ok again. So we thought maybe a memory leak since the computers and chrome run 24/7 (i think the version of chrome is 36, have to check). I will also run through some older logs to see if there was some strange behaviour, but nothing similar was reported in the last 6 months prior to the night the leap second was applied and everything run 24/7

Comment: By saying "on another site" do you mean one of the five sites? About the shifted elements you're probably right. What was the code update about?

Comment: yes one of the 5 sites but other then the first one. The first page's last update was a export to csv of 1 table and a few days before that a if statement for logins, if people with parameter 0(from db) logged in, it would give them 3 choices of a form and if people with paramter 2 logged in, it would give them only 1 form choice. The second's site update was adding about 5 variables that are stored in 5 new fields in the db table and adding a button to print a certain page.

Comment: "Of one table to csv". I would analyse the code for db manipulation. Has the export been used around the event?

Comment: the mentioned export most probably not but users use export of data to csv on daily base without any problems

Comment: Have you access to the exported data? The export were possibly a bit different than on the other times - even though I guess they aren't it's a try worth I think.

Comment: i checked. the mentioned added export was lastly executed a week before the incident. and yes i have access to the data but there seems to be nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the problem.

Seems that after a power outage chrome restored a different session pointing to another server (copy of the one hosting all the sites but no master slave relation) and users used that since i found the data on the other server.

The other server runs the same sites and db for testing purposes. Deleted user logins from the testing server and cleared browser history on users computers.